# Get Yii model class based on type

Tags: php, yii

Is there any built in support in Yii for typed models? For instance, If I have a class called Flashlight, Lock, and Folder that all extend my Product active Record model and I want to make sure it the typed class rather than the generic via Yii relations, how would I do that?

Currently I am overwriting __call and I'm not really happy about it. I feel like this is probably a common need.

Answer (score 2):

this is called [single table inheritance](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/198/single-table-inheritance/).

Basically you overwrite the [instantiate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#instantiate-detail) method of the model to return the class you need:

```
// protected/models/Product.php
protected function instantiate($attributes){
    switch($attributes['type']){
        case 'flashlight':
            $class='Flashlight';
        break;
        case 'lock':
            $class='Lock';
        break;
        case 'folder':
            $class='Folder';
        break;
        default:
            $class=get_class($this);
    }
    $model=new $class(null);
    return $model;
}
```