# Getting specific model instance based on attribute data yii2

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have the following table

`OrderItem(id, service_item_id, special_service_item_id,...)`

In my `OrderItem` class I specified the relation

```
class OrderItem extends ActiveRecord
{
   ...
   public function getServiceItems()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(ServiceItem::className(), ['id' => 'special_item_id']);
   }

   public function getSpecialItems()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(SpecialItem::className(), ['id' => 'service_item_id']);
   }
   ... 
}
```

By this way I can get the proper instances of my Serviceitems:

```
$order = Order::findOne([123]);
//An Array of ServiceItems
$serviceItems = $order->serviceItems;
//An Array of SpecialItems
$specialItems = $order->specialItems;
```

But now I want to extend my `SpecialItem`, in fact my `SpecialItem` is extended from the `ServiceItem`. All items are saved in the same table, but I have to calculate some values in another way when I have a `SpecialItem`.

Sure I just can add one extra column `extra_speacial_item_id` and define a relation`getExtraSpecialItem()`, but I think this is not a good way. (What if I want to extend more and more?)

However I found there is a mechanism in YII/ YII2 called [single table inheritance at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974846/4575082), where I overwrite the `instantiate()` method of the `BaseActiveRecord` ([source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L1090)). In the other answer they use it as a factorymethod. How should I implement it? My thoughts were:

```
class ServiceItem extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function instantiate($attributes){
        switch($attributes['class_name']){
            case SpecialItem::className():
                $class = SpecialItem::className();
            break;
            case ExtraSpecialItem::className():
                $class = ExtraSpecialItem::className();
            break;
            default:
                $class = get_class($this);
        }
        $model = new $class(null);
        return $model;
    }
}
```

If I'm getting it right, I have to place all new children of ServiceItem in the `instantiate()` method. Then I should alter the table to:

`Order(pk_id, fk_service_item_id, class_name, ...)`

Now I can access my items in 2 ways:

1. **Only use the Method** `getServiceItems()`

   ```
   $order = Order::findOne([123]);
   //An array of mixed Servicetypes, depending on class_name field
   $serviceItems = $order->serviceItems;
   ```
2. **Modify the relations in** `OrderItem`

   ```
   class OrderItem extends ActiveRecord
   {
       ...
       public function getServiceItems()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(ServiceItem::className(), ['id' => 'special_item_id'])
               ->where(['class_name' => ServiceItem::className()]);
       }

      public function getSpecialItems()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(SpecialItem::className(), ['id' => 'service_item_id'])
               ->where(['class_name' => SpecialItem::className()]);
      }

      public function getExtraSpecialItems()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(ExtraSpecialItems::className(), ['id' => 'service_item_id'])
               ->where(['class_name' => ExtraSpecialItems::className()]);
      }
      ... 
   }
   ```

   Accessing the items like above:

   ```
   $order = Order::findOne([123]);
   //An Array of ServiceItems
   $serviceItems = $order->serviceItems;
   //An Array of SpecialItems
   $specialItems = $order->specialItems;
   //An Array of ExtraSpecialItems
   $extraSpecialItems = $order->extraSpecialItems;
   ```

Is there another (better) way of getting the instance of a model or are these the only suitable soulutions? Is the way of overwriting the `instantiate()` method correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way

`order_item` table with a MANY_MANY with `item_type` table. `item_type(id, type,other_stuffs)`. (type = service, special, etc)

The junction table `order_item_type` (or something) would have the `order_item_id` and `item_type_id` for the primary composite key.

Then

```
class OrderItem extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function getOrderItemTypes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItemType::className(), ['order_item_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getServiceItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->via('orderItemTypes')
            ->where("type = service");
    }

    public function getSpecialItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->via('orderItemTypes')
            ->where("type = special");
    }

}
```

or something like

```
class OrderItem extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function getOrderItemTypes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItemType::className(), ['order_item_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getItemTypes($type = null)
    {
         return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->via('orderItemTypes')
            ->filterWhere(['type' => $type]); //not sure if you can do this, but looks cool. if not, i'm sure you get what i mean.
    }

}
```

Benefits of this database design are normalization, and flexibility.

[for reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data/)

Comment: Okay, you're right about the many-many table. But by this way I'm still getting only the Item-instance, not the SpecialItem. Just replace Item::className() with SpecialItem::className()? The second way is cool, indeed,  but I then need to overwrite the instantiate method, right?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally accepted your answer, because I haven't realized that with this my question about how to get the right instance of my service seems not to be regarded IMO

Comment: @Nordseebaer how does this not address getting the right instance of your service? You get the right instance of your service by calling the appropriate getter (`getServiceItems, getSpecialItems), or by passing the type you care about to the getItemTypes. Depends on which method you go with.

Comment: I'll get an instance of  `Item` this way, won't I? I mentioned this in my first comment: "`But by this way I'm still getting only the Item-instance, not the SpecialItem. Just replace Item::className() with SpecialItem::className()?`" Or do you expect me overriting the `instantiate` method like I mentioned in my question?

Comment: You won't have separate classes for each item type; the type is defined by the 'type' field in the Item model. calling `getItemTypes` as in the second example returns only the `Item`s of your specified type.

Comment: Ok, but I need this instance. I'll accept your answer anyways, cause I can use your code anyways. I get my instance from the instantiate method.